# Phone preview URL on confirmation SMS : generate fake validation / PHP

Tags: php, sms

we have a created for a client a web app (PHP) for meeting scheduling.

We send SMS to users in order to confirm their meeting, with a link to click to confirm their meeting.

Most of user have enable website preview in SMS on their phone.

How can I checked that the page is loading from a phone 'sms browser previewer' OR is really clicked / loaded by a human ?

A simple get_browser could not help, because browsers previewers are often the browser of the user... and it's not a bad robot crawling something..

The client's process is : the user click the link received on his phone, the meeting is confirmed.

Any tips ? 
Can't find any idea how to detect that and prevent 'false validation'.

thanks !

Comment: Tip : You can set a http cookie when the user clicks on your link

Comment: Nice idea, but in EU this is not legal except if the user accepts the cookie... so, it can't work that way

Comment: Just try to remove `http` or `https` from the url. The link should look like `www.url.com/something`. Because some rich URL previewers are not rendering pages without `http/https`

Comment: @Nanogramme GDPR doesn't forbid technical cookies. You still can set cookies without any personal information in it and it's absolutely legal. http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm

Comment: @Nanogramme And you can try javascript with `onload()` event. Previewer doesn't trigger any javascript event. You can do your confirmation logic with javascript

Comment: @JulienBourdic exact, you're right, I think i'm going your way, thanks !

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar ok thanks, I'll try with cookie first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, cookie trick works :

in wp function :

```
   function set_new_cookie_conf() {
    setcookie( 'confirm_cookie', 'human', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie_conf');
```

in confirm function :

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['confirm_cookie'])) {
               //DO THE JOB

             }
```